# Strange results with ModelingToolkit.jl

Tags: julia, modeling, symbolic-math

When I tried ModelingToolkit.jl package with the tutorial example

```
using ModelingToolkit
@variables t
@derivatives D'~t
z = t + t^2
expand_derivatives(D(z))
```

I had a wrong answer. Instead of having `1+2t`, I had `2t`.

[image: Screen capture]

This strange thing occurred when I used the environment @v1.5 (when I installed Julia, there was a message saying that the path length is greater than 50 characters, so I shortened the path to just "v1.5"). If I use the environment @JuliaPro_v1.5.2-1, however, I have correct answer `1 + (2 * t)`.

[image]

Is it a bug or is my system missing some other packages? The version of ModelingToolkit.jl I am using is 3.14.2.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce. MTK v4, the current release, seems to be fine.

Comment: I checked the version of MTK and found that under environment @JuliaPro_v1.5.2-1, it is 4.0.1. It's fine with this version.

Comment: Yeah so I think there's not much more to say other than, we know there was a bug in a much earlier version of MTK where it could drop derivative terms, there was a patch added almost 6 months ago to handle that, so use a newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine on MTK v4 (and a lot of earlier versions, but at least any v4.x is recommended these days anyways) so it could be a bug of an earlier version. The suggestion is to just use a newer version, which all downstream packages do, so for the most part this shouldn't be an issue.